# Removing the texts within a comment block ?* */ in python

Tags: python

My input file `test.sas` file looks like below:

```
My    
Name is Joe
How are you?;
/* Comment 1 */
/*Comment 2 
blah blah
blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah;*/
/* Comment 3 */
I am great
```

When I use the following code I get the result that is right after the code:

```
writing = True

with open('test.sas', 'r') as file:
    with open('output.sas','w') as out:
        for line in file:
            if writing:
                if '/*' in line:
                    writing = False
                else:
                    out.write(line)
            elif '*/' in line:
                writing = True
```

the result:

```
My    
Name is Joe
How are you?;
```

But I would like to get the following result:

```
My    
Name is Joe
How are you?;
I am great
```

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Basically I want to remove the text within the comment block and write the rest to the output file.

Comment: You can only detect `/*` OR `*/` on a line because of your `elif` (not lines with both). Change that to an `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your final

```
        elif '*/' in line:
            writing = True
```

to

```
        if '*/' in line:
            writing = True
```

That way you can hit both statements if they both exist on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some comments showing the status of your `writing` variable at the end of each line.

```
My                     //True
Name is Joe            //True
How are you?;          //True
/* Comment 1 */        //False
/*Comment 2            //False
blah blah              //False
blah blah blah         //False
blah blah blah blah;*/ //True
/* Comment 3 */        //False
I am great             //False
```

Do you see where the problem comes in? Since the if-statement can is only evaluated once per line (once per loop), it does not set `writing` to `True` after lines that have both the `/*` and `*/`.

To check for both of the comment signs on a single line, allow both if-statements to work in one loop. Change `elif '*/' in line:` at the end of your program to `if '*/' in line`. This way, it can set to writing at the end of each loop, *even if it set writing to False at first!*

Answer (score 0):

### One Option may be to use regex (re.sub()) to match your quotes and substitute it with an empty string.

[More on Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

The re.sub() method is for "substituting matches" with something else

re.sub(pattern, substitute, string)

Pattern: (/*[\s\S\w\W]**/\r?\n?) - catch everything between quotes followed by maybe a return or newline

```
import re

with open('text.sas') as f:
    string = f.read()

pattern = r'(/\*[\s\S\w\W]*\*/\r?\n?)'

new_string = re.sub(pattern, '', string)
print(new_string)
""" Output:
My    
Name is Joe
How are you?;
I am great
"""
```